# pageProperty and inline IF condition

Tags: grails, if-statement, gsp

I'm using the pageProperty function to drive some of my menus that are in my layout.  I need to apply specific classes to links depending on which meta.nav pageProperty returns.  Right now, it looks like this...

```
<g:if test="${pageProperty(name:'meta.nav') == 'support'}">
  <g:link class="selected" ...>support</g:link>
</g:if>
<g:else>
  <g:link ...>support</g:link>
</g:else>
```

I'd like to clean this up, however, this does not work

```
<g:link class="${pageProperty(name:'meta.nav') == 'support' ? selected : null}" ...>support</g:if>
```

I've tried several different variations of paranthesis and none seem to get what I need.  For example:

```
${(pageProperty(name:'meta.nav') == 'support') ? selected : null}
${(pageProperty(name:'meta.nav') == 'support' ? selected : null)}
```

Just can't seem to get it to act right.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a wild stab in the dark, how about:

```
${ pageProperty(name:'meta.nav').equals( 'support' ) ? 'selected' : null }
```

Not as groovy, but might be less confusing to the parser (it looks like something somewhere is getting confused and dumping `== support` out where it shouldn't)

Answer (score 1):

I would try making the true condition a String:

```
${(pageProperty(name:'meta.nav') == 'support') ? 'selected' : null}
```

It may be trying to access a variable named `selected` within the GSP script, which would be undefined.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  In the rendered HTML I end up with this: <a =="support" class="selected" href="/support/index">support</a>

Comment: The class="support" part is working but I end up with the extra =="support" for some reason.

Comment: @Gregg No idea if it will work, but does `${ pageProperty(name:'meta.nav').equals( 'support' ) ? 'selected' : null }` get you closer?